# Несколько вопросов по Python

Tags: python

Учу Python с помощью Youtube и в процессе набросал несколько вопросов:

**1)** "O: Циклический сдвиг вправо. Решите эту задачу в две строки. Ввод: 1 2 3 4 5. Вывод: 5 1 2 3 4":

Решил так:

```
print(sorted([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], key=lambda x: x % 5 == 0, reverse=True))
>>> [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Вопрос: Почему это работает именно так?

**2)** Вопрос: Чем отличается функция `sorted()` от функции `filter()`?

**3)** Вопрос: Подскажите, что делать после основной части Python-а: Декораторы, Замыкание и т.п.? Учить ООП, или начинать решать на Python-е различные задачи?

**4)** (Добавил) Какие сайты посоветуете для практики начального и среднего уровней?

Comment: Уберите 3 и 4 вопросы, потому что 1) на них нельзя дать объективный ответ; 2) слишком много вопросов в 1 вопросе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - неправильно у вас. это не сдвиг. можно так

```
a = input().split()
print(*(a[4:]+a[:4]))
```

2 - sorted - сортирует, filter - фильтрует

3 - начинай решать сразу

4 - https://praktikum.yandex.ru/profile/backend-developer/

Answer (score 2):

Нужно просто посмотреть, чему равно выражение ключа сортировки `lambda x: x % 5 == 0` на элементах списка:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x % 5 == 0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])))
[False, False, False, False, True]
```

При сортировке действует правило `True > False`, плюс к тому задан ключ `reverse=True`, т.е. сначала пойдут элементы, ключ которых больше (а не меньше, как по умолчанию). Таким образом, сначала пойдёт элемент, которому соответствует `True` (это `5`), а потом элементы, которым соответствует ключ `False` (в том порядке, в котором они были изначально). Что мы и наблюдаем. Но к сдвигу это решение и правда не имеет отношения.

Что касается `sorted` и `filter` это сортировка и фильтрация. Сортировка сортирует элементы с помощью функции сравнения, фильтрация оставляет элементы по условию, а не прошедшие фильтрацию элементы отбрасывает.

По третьему вопросу - делайте что хотите, зависит от ваших личных обстоятельств.

Comment: может стоит упомянуть, что в Python используется "стабильный" алгоритм сортировки, т.е. такой, который не меняет порядок одинаковых элементов ? ;)